# How to convert export line from bash to fish(variable expansion shortcuts)?

Tags: fish

I have a bash profile as to add a ':' if LIB exist, skip the ':' when LIB not defined.

```
export LIB="{LIB:-}${LIB:+:}/example/lib"
```

If run in fish, it will show

```
 ${ is not a valid variable in fish.
```

Any trick to convert this line to fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: In this simple case, try

```
set -gx LIB (string join : -- $LIB /example/lib)
```

This will construct a string with `string join` - if $LIB was set, it'll add it and a `:` before "/example/lib", if it wasn't it won't.

The underlying thing here is that fish doesn't have these variable expansion shortcuts like `${foo:+-/%#}` and such.

The intention here is to do something similar to what you would do with $PATH - "add :/foo if $PATH is set, or set it to /foo otherwise".

For $PATH, because it is a list in fish (as it is a [PATH variable](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#path-variables) - these are automatically joined/split with ":"), you would simply do

```
set -gx PATH $PATH /foo
```

You could define your variable $LIB as a path variable like

```
set -gx --path LIB $LIB /example/lib
```

and fish would do the same for it. Now inside fish it would be accessible as a list so you could use `$LIB[1]` to get the first element, and outside of fish it would be available in the colon-delimited form so applications know what to do with it.

But if you don't want to do that, see the `string join` method above.

Comment: if I run `set -gx --path LIB $LIB /example/lib` twice, it will cause duplicate path, any `fish` way to solve this issue?

Comment: `contains -- /example/lib $LIB; or set -gx --path LIB $LIB`.